# Bad instruction 'lock' compiling for armeabi with the Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an application that includes a library originally compiled for version 3 of the Android NDK.  The application got set aside for a while, and now I'm trying to resurrect it on the latest (Windows 64 bit r8e) version of the NDK.  I've fixed most of the little quirks, but I am having problems compiling for armeabi.  Specifically I get a "bad instruction 'lock'" error.  From some searching around, I've gathered that this assembly isn't valid for arm - and in fact it compiles fine if I set APP_ABI to x86 - but what I don't understand is why it's generating what appears to be x86 code if I've selected arm to be built, especially since under r3 arm code can be generated from the same .cpp files.  Thanks.

Application.mk

```
APP_STL          := stlport_static
APP_MODULES      := DM
APP_CPPFLAGS     := -w -g
APP_ABI          := armeabi

include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# STLPORT_BASE  := $(NDK_WRAPPERS_BASE)/stlport
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -D__NEW__ \
                   -DANDROID \
                   -DOS_ANDROID

LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib \
                   -ldl \
                   -lGLESv1_CM \
                   -lEGL \
                   -llog

LOCAL_MODULE    := DM
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    sample/test/Test.cpp
```

Output

```
ndk-build.cmd V=1
"Compile++ thumb : DM <= Test.cpp
D:/Projects/testProj/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/sample/test/Test.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -ID:/Projects/testProj/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport -ID:/Projects/testProj/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl//gabi++/include -DANDROID -D__NEW__ -DANDROID -DOS_ANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack  -frtti   -w -g  -ID:/Projects/testProj/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  jni/sample/test/Test.cpp -o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/sample/test/Test.o
C:\Temp\ccIqfvxp.s: Assembler messages:
C:\Temp\ccIqfvxp.s:474: Error: bad instruction `lock'
C:\Temp\ccIqfvxp.s:474: Error: immediate expression requires a # prefix -- `add
r3,[r0,#4]'
C:\Temp\ccIqfvxp.s:531: Error: bad instruction `lock'
C:\Temp\ccIqfvxp.s:531: Error: immediate expression requires a # prefix -- `add
r3,[r4,#4]'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/sample/test/Test.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, someone had snuck some x86 assembly code in that I wasn't aware of.  I was able to #ifdef this out, and now it's working fine for arm.

Answer (score 0):

Recently had a similar issue with a debian build for arm on an x86 build machine.
Particularly with qt libs.
Project is built with standard [debian tools](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial)
in a chroot ([here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chroo) and `man -k chroot` for details).

./debian/control file is an important part of build process, that among other things, has fields:

```
Build-Depends:
...
Depends:
```

Here is a simple example:

```
Source: file-mon                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Section: non-free/embedded
Priority: extra
Maintainer: Dmytro Poliarush
Build-Depends: libqtcore4:armhf, libqt4-dev:armhf
Standards-Version: 3.9.d
X-Python-Version: >= 2.6 
X-Python3-Version: >= 3.2 
Homepage: http://www.harmonicinc.com

Package: file-mon
Architecture: any
Depends: libqtcore4:armhf
Description:  Mainly for running tests.
```

If architecture in Build-Depends is not specified explicitly like `libqt4-dev:armhf`, debian scripts, when preparing chroot to build the project, do `apt-get install libqt4-dev`. And in such case, at least on x86, the architecture defaults to `amd64`. And an assembler error is raised:

```
...
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dpoliaru/Documents/test/file-mon'
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall --std=c++14 -I /usr/include/qt4/ -I /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/ -DNDEBUG  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-z,relro -L /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtCore.so.4  file-mon.cpp   -o file-mon
/tmp/cckjHuQp.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cckjHuQp.s:53: Error: bad instruction `lock'
/tmp/cckjHuQp.s:54: Error: bad instruction `decl [r3]'
/tmp/cckjHuQp.s:55: Error: bad instruction `setne r2'
<builtin>: recipe for target 'file-mon' failed
make[1]: *** [file-mon] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dpoliaru/Documents/test/file-mon'
dh_auto_build: make -j1 returned exit code 2
debian/rules:22: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
...
```

Which basically means, that assembler made and attempt to insert some x86 into armhf exec.
Specifying explicit architecture `libqt4-dev:armhf`, requires build tools to install all the required headers, libs for armhf.